# Android Notification 'Cannot resolve method 'build()' from ABS Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-notifications

I am attempting to show a basic notification from a fragment in an ActionBarSherlock layout. I have been [following the tutorial here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm) as well as the one on the Android Developer pages, but I am getting the error 'Cannot resolve method 'build()' on the last line. I have imported `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat` and `.app.NotificationManager`

```
public void createNotification(){

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Title");
    mBuilder.setContentText("Text");
    mBuilder.setTicker("Ticker");
    mNotificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.build());
}
```

If I change the last line to `mNotificationManager.notify(1,mBuilder.getNotification());` it works. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

It worked with me for both build() and getNotification() .
FYI , Notification.Builder.build() is API level 16 so check your target.
Also check your imports and build paths and clean the project. If the problem persists try another android-support-v4.jar inside libs may be its corrupted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions, I'm set as API level 16. I have updated the question as I am using ActionBarSherlock, just in case it makes a difference.