# NotificationCompat.Builder: Cannot resolve method build()

Tags: android, notifications, builder

I have the following simple class that I would like to use to notify user of incoming messages (I will evolve it as the app goes). But for now, in the last line, there is the following error and I can't run it:

> Cannot resolve method build()

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class UserNotificationActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void triggerNoti() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21294231/2135363) but doesn't make any change

What am I doing wrong ?!

**P.S.**: *Target (& min) sdk = 21*

Answer (score 1):

Notification method is changed a bit in support V4 and above API level 19
. You can try the below code block.

```
public void sendNotification(String message, String title, Intent intent, int not_id) {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notification
                = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    } else {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.app_icon);
        notification
                = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                //.setColor(Color.parseColor("#1a4994"))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(not_id, notification.build());
}
```

Update for [NotificationChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443690/notificationcompat-with-api-26#comment85175448_44524976) :

```
    public void initChannels(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
        return;
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                                                          "Channel name",
                                                          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but sadly doesn't quite solve my dilemma as yet I have the same error !! Same error appears on your last line

Comment: Check your import  : import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

Answer (score 0):

```
private void createNotification(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationReceive.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,(int) System.currentTimeMillis(),intent,0);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Message");
        .setContentText("this is a tittle")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.schollo)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification.flags = notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
}
```