# How to create NotificationChannel for lower API's ( < 26 ) ?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-appcompat, notification-channel

How to create NotificationChannel for lower API's ( < 26 )?. Is there some way to do it with AppCompat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible. The Android OS does not support it. You can add the channelId to the notification with `NotificationCompat.Builder(Context context, String channelId)`, but the OS will ignore it pre-Oreo.

My collegue tested it on API 15, 22, 23, and 26: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45979726/1310343