# NotificationCompat v7 and Android O

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am having troubles with NotificationCompat v7 and Android O.
Since the implementation of the NotificationCompatV7 only implements the deprecated constructor ( [was deprecated in support library 26.0.0-beta1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#NotificationCompat.Builder(android.content.Context))) of the v4 version, I am not able to get Notifications to work.

Solution for NotificationCompat v4 was proposed here:
[NotificationCompat with API 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443690/notificationcompat-with-api-26)

but since there is this issue with the poor implementation of the v7 version (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62475846) I am not able to post notifications on Android O

Does anybody have a solution for this or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NotificationCompat v7 is now deprecated, you should use **NotificationCompat v4** (according to the comments on NotificationCompat v7 class ).

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use the static classes in {@link android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat}.
 */
```

Then you can build your notification (Kotlin):

```
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "your_notification_channel_name")                     
.setContentTitle("title")
[...]
```

Note: the latest support version is "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0"

Comment: Thank you for the response. 26.0.0 really got rid of my issues with the NotificationCompat.Builder from the support library beta release.