# How to disable default push notification in baidu

Tags: android, push-notification, baidu

I need to disable default baidu push notification. Instead i will use NotificationCompat builder to show notification. I am having hard time figure it out. I tried all the baidu custom notification builders but there having issue with multi line messages.

If anyone found the solution, please share here. Your answer is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotificationCompat with API 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443690/notificationcompat-with-api-26)

Comment: Hello @StefanCrain, This is not duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443690/notificationcompat-with-api-26. I am more interested in disabling default Baidu push notification. The question here is before going in to onNotificationArrived method of PushMessageReceiver the default push notification is start appearing in the notification area. I want to disable this somehow to customize the message.