# How to save and "replay" a notification on Android?

Tags: java, android

*Edit with an update at the bottom with the cause, but still no fix*

I am trying to capture a notification and later replay it once I dismiss it. From what I've been able to figure out so far, I can capture a notification, but when I try create a new notification using `NotificationManager.notify()`, nothing happens. No errors, nothing. Is this even something I should be able to do?

Maybe I am not taking the right approach and someone can suggest a better approach. Like I stated above, I want to be able to know when a user receives a notification and to capture the notification in its entirety, so even when it's dismissed, I can restore it. Maybe there is a way to restore things from the notification history but I haven't been able to figure out fully how that works yet. Here's the code I have so far. I can successfully listen to when a notification is posted or removed. The goal is to send a broadcast when a notification is posted with the notification id and the actual Notification itself (this part works I think), and when the button is pressed, recreate the notification. When I press the button, nothing happens.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int notification_id = -1;
    private Notification myNotify;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle extras = myNotify.extras;
                String title = extras.getString("android.title");
                String text = extras.getString("android.text");
                NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nManager.notify(notification_id, myNotify);
            }
        });
    }


    private MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("notification_restore");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (myReceiver != null)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        myReceiver = null;
    }

    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Here you have the received broadcast
            // And if you added extras to the intent get them here too
            // this needs some null checks
            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            notification_id = b.getInt("notification_id");
            myNotify = b.getParcelable("notification");
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private int notification_id;
    private Notification myNotify;

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if ((sbn.getNotification().flags & Notification.FLAG_GROUP_SUMMARY) != 0) {
            //Ignore the notification
            return;
        }
        notification_id = sbn.getId();
        myNotify = sbn.getNotification();

        Intent intent = new Intent("notification_restore");
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("notification_id", notification_id);
        b.putParcelable("notification", myNotify);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if ((sbn.getNotification().flags & Notification.FLAG_GROUP_SUMMARY) != 0) {
            //Ignore the notification
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

So it looks like the reason my notification isn't showing up is because it complains about not finding a channel, even though the notification I am trying to replay has one. The exact error is:

`E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=com.gevdev.notify, channelId=bugle_default_channel, id=0, tag=null, opPkg=com.gevdev.notify, callingUid=10086, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10086, notification=Notification(channel=bugle_default_channel pri=1 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0xff2a56c6 category=msg groupKey=bugle_notification_group_key sortKey=00 actions=2 vis=PRIVATE)`

I am still new to android, but my initial guess is that the channelId found `bugle_default_channel` isn't found under my package name, but I don't know how to fix this yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

Even though the notification that I am grabbing to replay has a channel ID, the NotificationManager doesn't have that notification channel registered. I figured it based off the code [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443690/notificationcompat-with-api-26). This is how to register it.

```
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = nManager.getNotificationChannel(myNotify.getChannelId());
                    if (notificationChannel == null) {
                        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(myNotify.getChannelId(), "Description Goes Here", importance);
                        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                        nManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);\
                    }
                }
```